# What is the image name for the iPad Pro 12" LaunchImage

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm trying to access the LaunchImage for iPad Pro 12" from my `media.xcassets`, but am having trouble finding the image name. For all the others, I can do something like:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-800-Portrait-736h"]
```

- `LaunchImage-800-Portrait-736h` (iPhone Portrait / iOS 8,9 / Retina HD 5.5") for iPhone 6/6s/7 Plus
- `LaunchImage-800-667h` (iPhone Portrait / iOS 8,9 / Retina HD 4.7") for iPhone 6/6s/7
- `LaunchImage-800-Landscape-736h` (iPhone Landscape / iOS 8,9 / Retina HD 5.5")  for iPhone 6/6s/7 Plus
- `???` (iPad Pro 12") for iPad 12.9"
- `LaunchImage-700-568h` (iPhone Portrait / iOS 7-9 / Retina 4) for iPhone 5/5s/SE
- `LaunchImage-700` (iPhone Portrait / iOS 7-9 / 2x) for iPhone 4/4s
- `LaunchImage-700-Portrait` (iPad Portrait iOS 7-9 / 1-2x) for iPad 9.7"
- `LaunchImage-700-Landscape` (iPad Landscape iOS 7-9 / 1-2x) for iPad 9.7"

[image: LaunchImage template inside media.xcassets]

Looking at Build Logs, it doesn't even look like the iPad Pro 12" asset is being compiled…

```
Showing All Messages
CompileAssetCatalog /Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app Resources/Media.xcassets
    cd /Users/thon/projects/MyApp-iPad
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/assetcatalog_dependencies --output-partial-info-plist /Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon --launch-image LaunchImage --compress-pngs --enable-on-demand-resources YES --filter-for-device-model iPad6,8 --filter-for-device-os-version 9.3 --sticker-pack-identifier-prefix com.opentable.MyApp.sticker-pack. --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 9.0 --platform iphonesimulator --product-type com.apple.product-type.application --compile /Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app /Users/thon/projects/MyApp-iPad/Resources/Media.xcassets

/* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
/Users/thon/projects/MyApp-iPad/Resources/Media.xcassets:./LaunchImage.launchimage/[iphone][736h][3x][portrait][full-screen][8.0]: notice: This launch image only applies to iOS 6.x and prior but the minimum deployment is 7.0 or later.
/Users/thon/projects/MyApp-iPad/Resources/Media.xcassets:./LaunchImage.launchimage/[iphone][667h][2x][portrait][full-screen][8.0]: notice: This launch image only applies to iOS 6.x and prior but the minimum deployment is 7.0 or later.
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon29x29@2x.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon29x29@3x.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon40x40@2x.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon40x40@3x.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon60x60@3x.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon29x29~ipad.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon40x40~ipad.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon76x76~ipad.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/AppIcon83.5x83.5@2x~ipad.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/LaunchImage-800-Portrait-736h@3x.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/LaunchImage-800-667h@2x.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/LaunchImage-700@2x.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/Assets.car
/Users/thon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gldvoiquamqxowfqvgcydhfgzead/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
```

Comment: Look inside the asset to see the name.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm not looking for the file name. Even if I renamed `LaunchImage-800-667h.png` to `abc.png`, I still access it by calling `[UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-800-667h"]`

Comment: Of course you are looking for a filename. The value passed to `imageNamed:` is the name of a file in your app's resource bundle. Build and run your app on the iPad Pro. Look inside the resulting .app to find the iPad Pro launch image.

Comment: You should not be using separate launch images for each of the different sizes. You should be using a single launch-image storyboard or xib file for _all_ the sizes.